# How to import my passwords from Google Chrome to Safari under MacOS/ OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, passwords, safari

I have a fully synced Chrome Browser version 53 (above 45 Chrome isn't working with the OSX keychain) and I need to import my saved passwords into my virgin safari browser.

It isn't possible to import into LastPass for e.g..
Firefox isn't a connection to help...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the lastpass issue. You can't access your account in Firefox?

Comment: I can install Lastpass-Plugin in Chrome and log in. But I can't import passwords from the chrome password manager, it is always shown as empty. And I finally don't want to use a pw manager like this. I only want my passwords from my google account in my apple cloud keychain.

Comment: So your saying that when you go to that tab with passwords in Chrome settings there is nothing there right?

Comment: no in chrome every password is available. But in the Lastpass extension... are no passwords to import listed from chrome password manager.

Answer (score 1):

Go to chrome password export and enable it:

`chrome://flags/#password-export`

Then you can go into settings/password:

```
chrome://settings/passwords
```

And export it from there into csv. You can import this csv to lastpass, firefox or keychain

[password/settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufXHG.png)